# How can I replace ~60 print entries in 5 different files using vim or sed?

Tags: python, vim, sed

Fabfile (directory) containing Python files:

```
print "DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True"+var
print "DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True"
#print "DEBUG cfn_stackname: "+cfn_stackname
```

To:

```
LOGGER.DEBUG("DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True"+var)
LOGGER.DEBUG("DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True"
LOGGER.DEBUG(""DEBUG cfn_stackname: "+cfn_stackname)
```

How can I replace all these entries with my Logger module?
Should I use vim or sed?

Comment: how about `Find & replace` in windows notepad ?

Comment: Lol, I hope that was a joke @reportgunner he's using a Linux distro as slightly hinted by [vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) and [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)

Comment: @Jaba it **was** a joke, but I was implying using sed is a bit overkill to replace measly 60 entries

Comment: lol, I figured.

Comment: Also, exact duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487925/how-can-i-replace-60-print-entries-in-5-different-files-using-vim-or-sed; please **do not cross-post** to multiple sites in parallel!

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/^#\?print \("DEBUG.*\)/LOGGER.DEBUG(\1)/' file
```

yields:

```
LOGGER.DEBUG("DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True"+var)
LOGGER.DEBUG("DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True")
LOGGER.DEBUG("DEBUG cfn_stackname: "+cfn_stackname)
```

Comment: That does not work on my MacBook.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: No error. The working code on my MacBook is: sed 's/print \(.*\)/LOGGER.DEBUG(\1)/' fabfile

Comment: @Dennis, ok, glad your problem is solved